# How to keep track of what iteration a do while loop is on?

Tags: java, loops, iteration, do-while

lets say i have a do while loop

```
int index = 20;
do {
    index --;

//stuff

} while (index > 0);
index = index + 1;
```

I want to be able to keep track of what iteration this do while loop is on so I can print it in console with something like this

```
System.out.println("current iteration number is = " + iterationnumber);
```

how would I be able to do this?

Comment: What is `index`?

Comment: index is the maximum number of times the do while loop will iterate, in this case, it is 20

Comment: What would be `20 - index` for each loop?

Comment: Please give the max variable a better name, like `max`. The name you have chosen is totally confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
startNumber= 20;
index = startNumber
do{
    ....
    index--;
    itterNum = startNumber-index;
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) class.

In your case:

```java
    final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(20);

    do {
        index.getAndDecrement();

        //stuff

    } while (index.get() > 0);
```

With the above example, you can retrieve the current iteration by printing `index` or `index.get()`.

Hope that helps.